# It's correct to make a run method inside the class to start the flow of the 'program'?

Tags: ruby

I wrote this scraper script to extract the job list from a website. And then to in order to practice I decide to try to transform this script into a class object.

The correct approach is to just call the methods you need as it is below.

```
teste = InfoJobs.new
teste.build_url
teste.get_page_values
teste.scraping
teste.writing
```

but I want to know if is ok to have a run method inside of my class and use self. to make the flow of the scrape program.

```
  def run
        self.build_url
        self.parsing(@url)
        self.get_page_values
        self.scraping
        self.writing
    end

teste.run
```

Comment: Why not a class method? `InfoJobs.run` that calls the first block of code that you have.

Comment: @anothermh There's an instance variable in there which is presumably customized per instance.

Comment: Not in the first block of code shown.

Comment: I dont have anymore this '@url' and I notice that I dont need to use self too.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking "should I create an abstraction layer around the numerous steps required to perform the operation so that the caller doesn't need to care about the particulars" then the answer is that's fine.

I'd prefer to write code that says `scraper.run` than five lines of confusing boilerplate which doesn't afford me any more control than the equivalent `run` method does.